# Tensorflow - possibility of implementing custom d3.js plots into TensorBoard

Tags: d3.js, tensorflow

As the question says. Should I be digging into the TensorBoard source files, or is there an easier way?
Anyone tried this? If at all it's possible, where do I start?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to go diving in the source, you could duplicate the tf-event-dashboard and replace the vz-line-chart.html component with your own d3 component with a similar API. It won't be trivial but it can be done.

We are currently working on a plugin system that will make this easier. Feel free to email me (danmane at google) with more info on what kind of custom plots you want to add and we can chat about how it would fit into the TensorBoard roadmap.

Comment: This helps. Thanks for the heads up.